# Want help to make Android layout same like attachd image

Tags: android, layout, screen

I am getting stuck with making android screen layout same like i have in my iPhone application. The iPhone screen layout is given in below image. Please anyone can help me out to make same screen for android. You can give me some idea with having some code snippet please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should be creating an XML-based layout. The Android SDK has a graphical layout tool that will help you with that.

Start looking into 9-patch images for your custom button graphics and setting your `android:background` attribute to them within a `<Button />`.  Make sure you use actual text for the buttons, not graphics of the text. You should probably use a `<RelativeLayout />` for the main layout, as that will let you target multiple screen sizes easily without a mess of nested `<LinearLayout />`s.

For the tinted area, just use a translucent PNG (with an alpha channel) instead of attempting to line up graphics.

Comment: can you suggest me which layout do i need to use for whole screen?    because, currently i m working with TableLayout, but it's to difficult to understood the concept. Can you anyway help me out to overcome?

Comment: I suggested the RelativeLayout already. TableLayout is really only meant for tabular data that you want to be in strict rows and columns, like a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

use relative layout to design this screen like use image for navigation bar and align it as parent top (use no title bar in mainfest) add its listener 
similarly you can align other text and image view